# Passing a parameter to a function only if not null

Tags: kotlin, default-parameters

I need to pass a nullable parameter to a function that only accepts non nullable objects, but has a default value defined.

Currently I'm using a let:

```
fun myFun(a:String = "qqq"): Whatever {...}

val myString:String? = getNullableString()

val myFunResult = myString.?let{myFun(it)}?:myFun()
```

This is verbose and it is no more possible when there's more than an optional parameter.
I'd need something like

```
val myFunResult = myFun(myString?:default)
```

Is there a pratical way to do this?

Comment: I notice that you're function is not returning anything!!

Comment: Yes, that's just an example to clarify the issue, you can forget about the assignment if you prefer  :) I'll correct it

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to repeat the default value outside of the function (I wouldn't) you are going to have to do some kind of conditional check. Personally speaking, I find the `let` expression hard to read when scanning code, and would probably just go with an `if`. Keep in mind that in Kotlin, `if` is an expression:

```
if(myString == null) myFun() else myFun(myString)
```

Comment: This is what i thougt to do in the first place. Was hoping to find some trick, but i guess we need to stick the good old if. Thank @Todd.

Answer (score 1):

You could allow passing nullable values as parameters into your function, change named default value to `null` and set the actual default value inside the function's body:

```
fun myFun(a: String? = null) {
    val a = a ?: DEFAULT_VALUE
    // rest of the function
}

val myFunResult = myFun(myString)
```

Comment: Indeed, but I don't always have control on the function I'm calling (moreover, this is hiding a bit the actual default value in the method body). Any other way?

Comment: @OldManofAran Yes, unfortunately you lose some clarity with this one. The other way for the sake of clean code would be just wrapping your current approach into another well named function that takes a nullable argument. I don't think there is anything else as Kotlin creates a synthetic method that calls the function with a hardcoded default value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you can't change the initial function you are calling. Writing a new function to call the initial function might be a more readable approach.

```
fun myFun(a:String = "qqq"): Whatever {...}
fun myNewFun(a:String? = null): Whatever = if(a == null) myFun() else myFun(a)
```